# Is there a way to generate publication quality tables in Jupyter?

Tags: r, latex, markdown, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I've been using Jupyter for some data analysis in R with irkernel but it seems that there is not an obvious workflow to generate tables that could then be used for publication. Mathjax doesn't support latex tables and markdown tables are pretty basic. Ideally there'd even be a way to programmatically generate the tables from variables in R. For an example, here is a table that I would consider complex and ready for publication.
[image: Den Boon, et al. 2005. “Development and Evaluation of a New Chest Radiograph Reading and Recording System for Epidemiological Surveys of Tuberculosis and Lung Disease.”]

I can run the totals on agreement, proportion of agreement, confidence intervals and Cohen's Kappa in Jupyter, but can't find a way to display them all nicely together in one table.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with publication ready tables in R but there should be functions which let you do this (`xtable` for html? pander for markdown?).

To display such html/latex/markdown code, have a look at the `IRDisplay` package: it provides `display_html()`, `display_markdown()`, and `display_latex()` which can be used to display such stuff (e.g. `IRdisplay::display_html("<h1>Headline</h1>)` would display a H1 headline in the notebook output area).

One problem might be that you want nice tables in both the browser/html and in an exported/converted notebook. For that you can either use `publish_mimebundle` similar to how it done in [`display`](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRdisplay/blob/master/R/display.R#L23) or, if your output has a specifc class implement `repr_html.your_class()`/`repr_latex.your_class()`/... (from `repr` package) for all formats you want. It will then display automatically (like print) and it will use the best format for output format (html in the browser, latex in a PDF). If you explicitly need to display such a thing (e.g. in a loop) use `IRdisplay::display(object)`.

[There are issues in the r kernel repos and e.g. pander about adding the appropriate `repr_xxx` functions to get that automatically. Hasn't happend yet...]

If you just want a nicer table in the browser/Notebook UI, use https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions together with the `table_beautifier` extensions, which adds bootstrap styling to the tables.